# How to control the float number precision in SymPy?

Tags: python, linear-algebra, sympy

I have prepared an augmented matrix as following

```
A = np.round(10*np.random.randn(5,5))
I = np.eye(5)
AI = np.hstack((A, I))
AI = sy.Matrix(AI)
AI
```

[image]

Now perform the row reduced form algorithm, the result of inverse matrix has lots of digits after point, could any one tell my how to control the precision of matrix object in SymPy?

```
AI_rref = AI.rref()
Ainv = AI_rref[0][:,5:]
Ainv
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `applyfunc` to apply either rounding to a given digit or the `evalf`/`n` method to give a certain number of significant figures.

```
>>> from sympy import randMatrix
>>> m = (randMatrix(3,3).row_join(eye(3))).rref()[0]
>>> m.applyfunc(lambda x: round(x, 3))
Matrix([
[1, 0, 0,  0.004, -0.022,  0.016],
[0, 1, 0,  0.015,  0.001, -0.006],
[0, 0, 1, -0.022,  0.027,    0.0]])
>>> m.n(3)
Matrix([
[1.0,   0,   0, 0.00404,  -0.0225,    0.016],
[  0, 1.0,   0,  0.0149, 0.000538, -0.00604],
[  0,   0, 1.0, -0.0216,   0.0268, 0.000228]])
```